MATLAB - Comparing each row of two matrices using ismember without loop
Say I have two matrices:
A = [1;
     2;
     3;
     4;
     5]

and
B = [1 1 2 1;
     2 3 3 4;
     5 5 5 5;
     1 4 4 4;
     5 5 1 2]

I need a resulting matrix showing how many times an item from A has appeared on the respective row in B, like this:
C = [3;
     1;
     0;
     3;
     2]

Currently, I am doing that using ismember inside of a for loop and adding the result per row. But it is taking forever because of the size of my matrices. Is there any way to do that without a loop?
Editing to show my current code:
for i=1:1:length(A)
    C(i) = sum(ismember(B(i,:),A(i)),2);
end

But, in reality, my matrices have over 500k lines, and I would love to make this code more efficient by removing the loop.

Loops in MATLAB are not slow. They used to be 20 years ago, but that's a long time ago. You don't want to do this without loops, you want to speed up your code. Show us your code, we might be able to point out how to speed it up.

Thank you, Cris! I have added my code to the question. Hope this helps

@CrisLuengo In my experience, although their speed has improved, loops are still slower than vectorized code in many situations. That seems to be the case here, as per Wolfie's timing

Short Answer
You can just use ==, which will use implicit expansion to compare each element of A to the entire row of B and output a logical array of matches, then sum across each row to count the matches
C = sum( A == B, 2 );

Depending slightly on how A and B are generated, it's often a good idea to avoid direct equality comparisons on floating point numbers (see here), so it might be more robust to make sure A and B are within some small tolerance, i.e.
tol = 1e-8;
C = sum( abs(A-B) < tol, 2 );

The subtraction here will use implicit expansion the same as == in the first example to propagate A across the columns of B.

Benchmarking
Out of interest I've done some benchmarking between four cases

Code exactly as posted in your question, which is a for loop without pre-allocating the output array C so it grows with the loop.
The same code but pre-allocating C as an array of NaN the correct size, this is typically a good way to speed up loops. Speed up vs (1) of ~18%.
The same pre-allocated loop but using == instead of ismember, since you're comparing integers I would expect == to be faster than ismember. Speed up vs (1) of ~62%.
The above code without using loops at all. The == or abs(..)<tol approaches are both similarly fast so I've only shown the latter. Speed up vs (1) of ~94%.

Results for test case with length(A) = 1e6 and 100 columns in B:
With loop and ismember:              0.65sec
With preallocated loop and ismember: 0.53sec
With preallocated loop and ==:       0.25sec
With no loop and ==:                 0.04sec

Your mileage may vary on these time savings depending on input matrix sizes, expected number of matches, etc. Full code below for you to test other cases.
Code:
N = 1e6;
A = (1:N).';
B = randi([1,N],N,1e2);

t = [ 
    timeit( @() withloop(A,B) )
    timeit( @() withloop_prealloc(A,B) )
    timeit( @() withloop_prealloceq(A,B) )
    timeit( @() noloop(A,B) )
    ];

fprintf( 'With loop and ismember:              %.2fsec\n', t(1) );
fprintf( 'With preallocated loop and ismember: %.2fsec\n', t(2) );
fprintf( 'With preallocated loop and ==:       %.2fsec\n', t(3) );
fprintf( 'With no loop and ==:                 %.2fsec\n', t(4) );

function withloop(A,B)
    for i=1:1:length(A)
        C(i) = sum(ismember(B(i,:),A(i)),2);
    end
end
function withloop_prealloc(A,B)
    C = NaN(length(A),1);
    for i=1:1:length(A)
        C(i) = sum(ismember(B(i,:),A(i)),2);
    end
end
function withloop_prealloceq(A,B)
    C = NaN(length(A),1);
    for i=1:1:length(A)
        C(i) = sum(B(i,:) == A(i),2);
    end
end
function noloop(A,B)
    C = sum( abs(A-B)<1e-8, 2 );
end


Exactly what I needed! Thank you so much for the help and very detailed response, Wolfie!
You're the best!
